# can you write extension methods on type arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I need to write an extension method on a byte[].  Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, just do :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Method(this byte[] current)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make the first parameter of type `byte[]`.